# How to do `MyClass<String>.class` in Java?

Tags: java, generics

How can call `public <T> T doit(Class<T> clazz);` using `MyClass<String>.class` as clazz where I can not instantiate or extend MyClass.

EDIT: 'David Winslow' and 'bmargulies' responses are correct `(MyClass<String>) doit(MyClass.class);` works for the original question BUT surprisingly when the method returns say `MyClass<T>` instead of `T` casting will not compile any more.

Edit: I have replaced List with MyClass and added the condition to my original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create expressions of type Class<List<?>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012306/how-to-create-expressions-of-type-classlist)

Comment: @Bozho See update. I had simplified my real situation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `List.class`.  Because of [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) type parameters to Java classes are entirely a compile-time construct - even if `List<String>.class` was valid syntax, it would be the **exact same class** as `List<Date>.class`, etc.  Since reflection is by nature a runtime thing, it doesn't deal well with type parameters (as implemented in Java).

If you want to use the Class object to (for example) instantiate a new List instance, you can cast the result of **that operation** to have the appropriate type parameter.

```
List<String> list = (List<String>)(ArrayList.class.newInstance());
```

Comment: "can't do this" is not a good way to describe technical issues.  Does the code compile? Is there an error at runtime? Does someone come and take away your keyboard every time you try to compile?

Comment: yes I was wrong, I removed my comment. I had another error too, I'm still working.

Answer (score 9):

I've seen similar questions asked several times, for example 
[Acquiring generic class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984053/acquiring-generic-class-type/4986248#4986248)

There are legitimate reasons to construct static generic types. In op' case, he would probably like to

```
MyClass<String> result = doit(MyClass<String>.class);
```

Without language syntax support, casting is the correct way to go. If this is needed quite often, the casting should be put in a method, as

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // may need a better method name
    static public <T2> Class<MyClass<T2>> of(Class<T2> tClass)
    {
        return (Class<MyClass<T2>>)(Class<?>)(MyClass.class);
    }
}

MyClass<String> result = doit(MyClass.of(String.class)); // no warning
```

We can supress the warning on that method alone, after making sure the cast is safe. Any call site will not see the warning.

This is all compile time casting game. At runtime all the type parameters are erased, and really only the naked class object is passed around. The `of` method will most likely be optimized off, so to JVM the last line is nothing but

```
MyClass result = doit(MyClass.class)
```

---

There are also times when at *runtime* we need a complete `MyClass<String>` type. A `ParameterizedType` object needs to be obtained to represent `MyClass<String>`.

When the two requirements are combined together, that is, we need a compile time expression regarding `MyClass` and `String` that will evaluate at runtime to a `ParameterizedType`

```
ParameterizedType type_MyClass_String = ???? MyClass ?? String ???
```

There is a technique involving an anonymous subclass of `MyClass<String>`

```
ParameterizedType type_MyClass_String = superTypeOf( new MyClass<String>(){} );
```

which I find quite disturbing.

Comment: Did you mean `return (Class<MyClass<T2>>) (Class<?>) MyClass.class;`?

Answer (score 2):

See http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/type/TypeReference.html and the references that it references for a comprehensive discussion of the issues around generics.

the bottom line is that, if you really want to work with generic types in this way, you have to stop using `Class` and start using `Type` and its subclasses.

Contrary to your comment on another answer, you can write `List<List<String>> obj = (List<List<String>>) doit(List.class);`, you just can't avoid a warning when you write it.

Answer (score 1):

Since after your update your question does not appear to be an exact [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012306/how-to-create-expressions-of-type-classlist):

You would need to call `getClass()` on an instance of `MyClass`. Better have a dummy static final instance somewhere:

```
public static final MyClass INSTANCE = new MyClass();
...
return (Class<MyClass<String>>) instance.getClass();
```

Comment: Cannot cast from Class<List> to List<String>

Comment: Cannot cast from Class<List> to Class<List<String>>

Comment: @JohnS but what stops you from instantiating it?

Comment: final class MyClass<T> {
 private MyClass() {
 }

 public static <T> MyClass<T> create(Class<T> clazz) {
  /*over simplified*/
  return new MyClass<T>();
 }
}

Comment: @JohnS - reflection? Or use the factory method with `create(Object.class)`

Answer (score 0):

`T` corresponds to `List`, so any reference to `String` as the generic paramter of `List` is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

> How to do `MyClass<String>.class` in
>   Java?

## You can't.

Generics in Java use type erasure; the type of the parametrized argument is enforced during compilation, but it is lost **after** compilation. The resulting byte code for an instance of a generic class does not contain any run-time meta-data on its arguments whatsoever.

As it is now, it is just not possible, a major language design blunder IMO.

Comment: But did you know about ParameterizedType http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html

Comment: ParameterizedType is a kludge IMO, and it is not the same (syntactically or semantically) as evaluating `MyClass<String>.class` just as one would with, say, `X.class` for an arbitrary class or interface. By default, one can call `X.class` w/o worrying about runtime or checked exceptions. OTH, ParameterizedType can only be made to work with classes extending generic classes (.ie. `class StringList extends ArrayList<String>`). Then, the JVM can keep track of `inherited` generic parameter types, but won't otherwise. Plus, you have to deal with potential exceptions when using it. Not the same.