# How can I do the same in java as in Scala 'classOf[List[String]]'?

Tags: java, scala

Here is a demo for Spark read Protobuf in scala: [SparkReadProtoBuf.scala](https://github.com/MammothData/spark-protobuf/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mammothdatallc/spark/SparkReadProtoBuf.scala)

I don't know how can I do the same in Java as in Scala: `classOf[BinaryWritable[MyProtocolBuffers.MyProtocolBuffer]]`

And I use the following java code has no effect:

```
JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, ProtobufWritable> rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
            path,
            MultiInputFormat.class,
            LongWritable.class,
            ProtobufWritable.class,
            conf);
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: It seems is not the reason of my java code.
I run the scala code and it has no effect too, just as no data in path, and with no other log information.
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

> BinaryWritable.class 
>   instead of ProtobufWritable.class

this link might be of help

[How to do `MyClass<String>.class` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207163/how-to-do-myclassstring-class-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, I have also tried `BinaryWritable.class`.
Perhaps it's not the real problem of my program.