# How do I get the type of a java parametarized collections class?

Tags: java, generics

In java, I get can get the type of any class using `ClassName.class`. But what if I want to get the type of a parametarized(generic) collection? `Collection<MyClass>.class` does not work.

This is what I want to do:

```
ParameterExpression<Collection<MyClass>> dateParameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Collection<MyClass>.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to how generics are implemented in Java (type erasure), there *is no* `Collection<MyClass>` class.  Just the standard `Collection` class.

Generics are effectively extra compile-time checks which only make it into the generated bytecode in a limited fashion.  In particular, objects do not know with which generic parameters they were instantiated, so you can't call e.g. `instanceof` at runtime to check this.

Most reflective calls (which includes use of the `Class` class) overlook generics, because you wouldn't get any type safety *anyway*.  Even if the runtime allowed you to access the `Collection<MyClass>` class, its `add` method would *still* take merely `Object` since this would just be syntactic sugar for getting the raw type `Collection`.  Java arguably makes the correct decision here by not allowing this potentially misleading syntax, so as it make it clear that generic classes don't actually exist at runtime.

Comment: Andrzej: Ok thank you. How would you solve the problem above? (question updated). Just suppress the warning?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you can either suppress the warning or use double casting (cast to the raw type `Class` and then back down to `Class<Collection<MyClass>>`) to get this to compile without errors.  Don't forget that not all warnings are necessarily bad - it's just the compiler saying "I can't tell if this is correct or not".  Situations like this, where it's obvious to the developer (but not the compiler) that this is correct, is what warning suppression was made for.

Answer (score 0):

[Acquiring generic class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984053/acquiring-generic-class-type/4986248#4986248)

```
public static <C extends Collection, E, T extends Collection<E>>
Class<T> cast(Class<C> classC, Class<E> classE)
{
    return (Class<T>)classC;
}

Class<Collection<MyClass>> clazz = cast(Collection.class, MyClass.class)
criteriaBuilder.parameter( clazz );
```

However, since only the raw class is passed at runtime, the library won't be knowledgeable about the detailed type, which might be neeed to do the job.

Such library should expand to accept `Type` which includes richer type info. The question now becomes how to write the `Type` of `<Collection<MyClass>>` at compile time. "Super Type Token" is one way.